# MS Access Simple form to populate many to many table

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a simple ms access db with the following tables:

```
Patient
    ID
    Name

Medication
    ID
    Name

PatientMedication
    ID
    PatientID
    MedicationID
```

This third table is a many to many table between Patient and Medication - recording what medications are taken by each patient.  I want to create a form that populates this table by allowing me to select a patient and a medication, and storing a new row to the PatientMedication table.

I've gotten as far as creating the form with the dropdowns, and added a button to save the selected rows to the db, but don't know how to make the button do the insert.  Do I have to write some VB code for the button?  Do I even need a button?  It seems that this is pretty trivial and I should be able to do it through some property of the form.  Or is there a simpler way of going about this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually handle it in several different ways.  Below are a couple of options.

### Option 1:

Set the `Record Source` property of the form `PatientMedication`.  Set the dropdowns `Control Source` to `PatientID` and `MedicationID`.  Then make sure that the `required` property of `PatientID` and `MedicationID` in the `PatientMedication` table is set to `Yes`.  Then when a user selects a value for the drop downs the record will be added to the database.  This assumes that the `ID` fields data type is set as `AutoNumber`.

### Option 2:

Don't set the `Record Source` property of the form to `PatientMedication`.  Don't set the dropdowns `Control Source`, leave them unbound.  Set the `MedicationID` dropdown's `Name` property to `txtMedicationID`.  Set the `PatientID` dropdown's `Name` property to `txtPatientID`.  Set the command buttons `Name` property to `cmdInsertRecord`.  Use the following code for the `On Click` event of the button:

```
Private Sub cmdInsertRecord_Click() 
  If (VBA.Strings.Len(txtPatientID & "") = 0) Then
    MsgBox "You must specify a Patient ID before adding the record.", , "ERROR: Missing Information"
    Exit Sub
  End If

  If (VBA.Strings.Len(txtMedicationID & "") = 0) Then
    MsgBox "You must specify a Medication ID before adding the record.", , "ERROR: Missing Information"
    Exit Sub
  End If  

  DoCmd.SetWarnings False
  DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO PatientMedication (PatientID, MedicationID) Values " & _
               "('" & txtPatientID & "', '" & txtMedicationID & "')"
  DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Sub
```